# groovy-macro is loaded in version 2.5.8 and you are trying to load version 2.5.12

Tags: gradle, tomcat, groovy, spock

I am using Eclipse 4.13, version 4.0.0 of the plugin with Groovy compiler 2.5 and Spock 2.0-M2.

We are using Gradle to manage our dependencies. Recently we have updated our Groovy libraries to 2.5.12 and since then when executing Spock tests we are getting the following error:

groovy-macro is loaded in version 2.5.8 and you are trying to load version 2.5.12

Seems that Spock is fetching transitively version 2.5.8. I was thinking of avoiding Spock from fetching 2.5.8, but just modifying manually the classpath of the project executing the Spock test and making sure that all the Groovy libraries are version 2.5.12 doesn't seem to help as I am getting the same error.

Comment: Is this problem specific to eclipse (does it work with the CLI)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Similar version clashes can occur in Maven, which is what I am working with. There you would use a `<dependencyManagement>` section (maybe imported from a BOM) in order to deal with that. I am sure that similar ways for version management exist in Gradle, which I do not use actively. Anyway, the best way to ask questions around here is to present an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You did not even show your Gradle build file. Nobody can debug your prose, though.  Imagine that you ought to help someone else with that kind of information. Could you?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem with maven project, gmaven plugin and spock 1.3.

I use maven dependency management and imported the `groovy-bom` to resolve version conflicts, but that doesn't help.

You have to use exact the same groovy version that spock depends on.

For spock 2.0-M2, the `gradle.build` says:

```
 if (variant == 2.5) {
      groovyVersion = "2.5.8"
      minGroovyVersion = "2.5.0"
      maxGroovyVersion = "2.9.99"
    } else if (variant == 3.0) {
      groovyVersion = "3.0.0"
      minGroovyVersion = "3.0.0"
      maxGroovyVersion = "3.9.99"
    } else {
    throw new InvalidUserDataException("Unknown variant: $variant. Choose one of: $variants")
  }
```

I don't know why another `groovy-macro` is loaded although `mvn dependency:tree` prints the proper `groovy-macro` version.